# timer_settime fails even though all members of the itimerspec are set

Tags: c, timer, posix, errno

So, this code was working just fine until recently, when we decided to move it to a Lubuntu 12.04 system.  The call to timer_settime returns EINVAL, and running it under gdb I've confirmed that all of the fields of ts are within 0 and 999999999 at the time that it is called:

```
1067        if(-1 ==timer_settime(tid,0,&ts,NULL))
(gdb) print ts
$1 = {it_interval = {tv_sec = 0, tv_nsec = 200000000}, it_value = {tv_sec = 0,
tv_nsec = 0}}
```

Since this should be the only thing that can cause it to return EINVAL I'm very much puzzled. Maybe there's something obvious here that i'm missing.

```
struct sigevent sev;
struct itimerspec ts;
timer_t *tid;
//actually point the pointer at something.
tid = calloc(1,sizeof(timer_t));
//make sure there's no garbage in the structures.
memset(&sev,0,sizeof(struct sigevent));
memset(&ts,0, sizeof(struct itimerspec));
//notify via thread
sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
sev.sigev_notify_function = SwitchThreadHandler;
sev.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = tid;
ts.it_value.tv_sec =0;
ts.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
ts.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
ts.it_interval.tv_nsec = 200000000;
if(-1 == timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME,&sev,tid))
{
    retval = EX_SOFTWARE;
    fprintf(stderr,"Failed to create timer.");
    free(tid);
    return retval;
}

if(-1 ==timer_settime(tid,0,&ts,NULL))
{
    int errsv = errno;
    fprintf(stderr,"timer_settime FAILED!!!\n");
    if(errsv == EINVAL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"INVALID VALUE!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"UNKOWN ERROR: %d\n",errsv);
    }
    return EX_SOFTWARE;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`timer_settime` is documented as taking a `timer_t` as the first argument, not a `timer_t *` like `timer_create`. It will fail with `EINVAL` if `timerid` is invalid.

Therefore, you should pass `*tid` as the first argument.

Note that your compiler should have issued a warning for this.

Comment: Strangely,  gcc -Wall didn't give a peep about this, and it worked perfectly on three out of the four environments we've tried it on. Weird. Well, now it no longer fails, but the timer never fires, so you've answered the question I asked.

Comment: timer_t is void* on linux, so timer_settime will accept any pointer as the first argument without warning.